# convergence of $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be compact and $C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$ the space of all $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous functions. Define $||u||_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)}:=||u||_{\sup}+\sup\limits_{{x,y\in \Omega\space\&\space x\ne y}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$ and consider $(C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),||u||_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)})$ and $\alpha\in]0,1]$ .

How can you prove that  for any sequence in bounded closed set of $(C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),||u||_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)})$ there exists a convergent subsequence  (concerning the **uniform norm**) and it limes is in  $(C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega))$?

Comment: Subsequence of what?

Comment: @Norbert of any function on a bounded closed subset of $(C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),||u||_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)})$

Comment: You question is still not well phrazed. The answer to your qustion (as it formulated) is - "yes, of course!". Take some $u$ in closed bounded subset $F$ and consider constant sequence $u_n=u$.

Comment: May be you meant that for any sequence in bounded closed set there exist convergent subsequence such that ...

Comment: Look up Arzelà-Ascola theorem (e.g. on Wikipedia).

Comment: @Norbert right... sry. I edited it. So how can you show it?

Comment: I've seen your edit. Now use hint given by D. Thomine

Comment: @Norbert : I am questioning to myself how could i get equi- continuity  ?

Comment: sry but I don't get it. I haven't heard of Arzelà-Ascoli before.

Comment: @Sheldor : Its  very useful to learn Arzela Ascoli theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1) Using estimations of norms prove that if set $F$ is bounded in $(C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),\Vert\cdot\Vert_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)})$ then it is bounded in $(C^{0}(\Omega),\Vert\cdot\Vert_{C^{0}(\Omega)})$

2) If $F$ is bounded in $(C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),\Vert\cdot\Vert_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)})$ then $$
\exists C>0\quad\forall u\in F\quad \forall x,y\in\Omega\quad |u(x)-u(y)|\leq C|x-y|^\alpha
$$

3) Prove that 2) implies equicontinuity

4) From 1) and 4) you see that $F$ is relatively compact in $(C^{0}(\Omega),\Vert\cdot\Vert_{C^{0}(\Omega)})$.

5) If you get to this paragraph it is remains to prove uniform convergence. Using estimations of norms prove that if sequence $\{u_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ converges in $(C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega),\Vert\cdot\Vert_{C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)})$, then it converges in $(C^{0}(\Omega),\Vert\cdot\Vert_{C^{0}(\Omega)})$.

6) From statement of paragraph 2) prove that the limit function is $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous.

Comment: I didn't get what $C^0(\Omega)$ means . is it same as taking $\alpha =1$

Comment: I don't know what is $\gamma$, but $(C^0(\Omega),\Vert\cdot\Vert_{C^0(\Omega)})$ is the space of continuous functions on $\Omega$ with $\sup$ norm.

Comment: sorry , i meant $\alpha$.

Comment: @Norbert isn't it enough to say that all Hölder-continuous functions are uniformly continuous so it follows (1) ?

Comment: @sheldoor, I don't think so. Generally spaeking the family of uniformly continuous functions is not uniformly bounded - consider constants.